# Add Route to Navigation Stack without Pushing the Screens to the Stack

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I want to add some `routes` to the Navigation Stack but don't want to Push those Screens. Is it possible to give a Stack in `flutter` navigation?

For example -- 
I have 3 screens. `A`, `B` and `C`.

- So directly I want to go to the screen `C` and back button on `C` should take me to `B` and `B`'s back button should take me to the `A`.

I don't want to do something like this --

```
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/A");
Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/B");
Navigator.pushNamed(context,"/C");
```

I just want to push `C` and keep remaining 2 routes on the stack without pushing those screens.